# How to initialize unowned stored properties in a swift subclass?

Tags: swift

I have a custom swift subclass of UICollectionViewController, and it has the property `unowned var mainController`. I cannot figure out how to initialize this property. If I try to initialize it before calling `super.init`, Xcode complains about 'self' being used before super.init. If I try to initialize it afterwards, Xcode complains about property 'self.mainController' not initialized at super.init call.

In general, is it possible to have an unowned variable as a property of a subclass in swift?

```
class CustomCollection: UICollectionViewController {

    unowned var mainController: MainController

    convenience init(mainController: MainController) {
        var collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        self.mainController = mainController
        self.init(collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
    }

    override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have only one init method where you are setting the value of mainController or initialize mainController in all of your init methods before calling super.init.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work in a playground file for me...

```
class Fruit {

    var taste:String

    init(){
        taste = "sweet"
    }

    deinit{
        println("Deinitializing Fruit")
    }
}

class Apple:Fruit{

    let color: UIColor
    unowned var meme:NSObject

    override init () {
        color = UIColor.greenColor()
        meme = "The Big Apple"
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init ( newMemeValue: AnyObject) {
        self.init()
        self.meme = newMemeValue as! NSObject
    }
}

var redApple:Apple?
redApple = Apple(newMemeValue: "A Bigger Bite")
println("\(redApple)")
var color = redApple!.color
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't feel like the best solution, but this is what I ended up doing:

```
class CustomCollection: UICollectionViewController {

    unowned var mainController = MainController()

    convenience init(mainController: MainController) {
        var collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        self.init(collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
        self.mainController = mainController
    }

    override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }
```

and in MainController:

```
class MainController: UIViewController {

    lazy var customCollection: CustomCollection = CustomCollection(mainController: self)

    init () {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

@Shoaib is right that mainController needs to be initialized in all init functions, so I just ended up initializing it at the top and setting it again after calling super.init().